# Redirect to an Angular route from server side using Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, redirect, angular-routing

My app is composed of 2 modules: an Angular 5 `uimodule` and a Spring Boot REST `servermodule`. I am using the `frontend-maven-plugin` to build the `uimodule` and copy its resources files into `META-INF/resources` folder to help Spring Boot discovering them. So the 2 modules run in the same domain (`http://localhost:8080`).

Now I am struggled with the implementation of the point 3 of this workflow:

1-A user registers in the application (`uimodule` posts users's data to the server)

2-After received data, the `servermodule` sends a validation mail to the user with validation link.

3-When the user clicks on the link, the server validates the user and should **redirect him to the login page.**

The `/login` route already exists in the `uimodule`. Now my question is:

How can I redirect the user to the login route from the server side?

I tried this, but not work :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/activate" )
public class ActivationController {

  @GetMapping
  public String activate() {
    return "redirect:/login";
  }
}
```

The same route (`http://localhost:8080/login`) works when I click on the defined login button (in `index.html`) but doesn't work when it comes from the server or when I write it manually (I got a 404 error)

Help!

Answer (score 1):

the server doesn t know that url, you have to redirect this to your angular main page, you need a controller that map the url

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String redirect() {
    return "index";
}
```

where index is your angular page

Comment: And how I redirect the user to the login page after redirect him to the home page?

Comment: in angular all app is in one page, is up to you  to decide what renderer, you can use a auth service that check if you are log and  provide to show the login page

Answer (score 1):

I had the same functionality to be implemented with the same setup (i.e Angular 8 and Spring Boot as a single application with gradle build), only difference was I was using webflux module.
After some research, I found that I need an implementation of UrlBasedViewResolver to handle the forwards or redirects. So I included the 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf' module for the ViewResolver to be configured and voila, it worked.

So same like you, after sending the mail and after the user clicked the link to verify the email, it got redirected to the page I wanted. A small code snippet follows..

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/verify/{email}")
  public Mono<String> verify(@PathVariable String email)
  {
    log.info("Verifying email {}", email);
    Subscribe subscribe = new Subscribe();
    subscribe.setEmail(email);
    subscribe.setVerified(false);
    Example<Subscribe> es = Example.of(subscribe);

   return this.subscribeRepository.findOne(es)
                                       .doOnSuccess(sub ->
                                                    {
                                                      log.info("Setting verified to true");
                                                      sub.setVerified(true);
                                                      this.subscribeRepository.save(sub)
                                                                              .subscribe();
                                                    })
                                       .then(Mono.just("redirect:/verified"))
                                       .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("redirect:/error"));
```

I already had the Angular routes for verified and error. Hope this will help.